# Renaming the Hosting URL for a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-apps

I just started developing a Facebook App. I'm having trouble understanding some things working with Heroku, the free hosting platform for the apps.

So I created the App on Facebook. And from Heroku, I renamed the App. And from Facebook under App on Facebook, I changed **Canvas URL** and **Secure Canvas URL** accordingly. But the **Hosting URL** still has the old URL which was given when I created the app. The only option given is to remove it. How can I edit this and give the new URL?

Guidance would be greatly appreciated as I'm really confused with this. Thank you.

Comment: I actually doesn't matter, make sure you update the canvas url and site url. I should work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm same problem like you.

The reason why removing Hosting URL is I don't want auto-generated url something like 'something-####.herokuapp.com'

When I removed this url, however, Facebook authentication doesn't work anymore.
So my recipe is,

- Change app name whatever you want.
- Just remove it hostring url.
- Reconfigure heroku's config var using CLI.

  `$heroku config:add FACEBOOK_APP_ID=yours FACEBOOK_SECRET=yours`

You can figure it out `heroku config -s` current variables.
Check **Readme.md** in your Facebook/Heroku sample app folder for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar issue when I decided to change the app name on heroku. After a little bit of research I realized that if toy only change the items it allows you to change, facebook will still direct to your heroku app page.